# How to define condition based on get url value

Tags: php, if-statement, get, conditional-statements

When a user clicks on "List View" link then I want to show them the "List View" HTML and when they click on "Grid View" I want to show "Grid View" HTML.
I've defined the following links to click-

```
<a href="?view=list">List View</a> <br>
<a href="?view=grid">Grid View</a>
```

Then I defined the following condition with PHP get method to show user the desired output-

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['view'] ) == 'list' ){
  echo "This is List view";
}else if( isset($_GET['view'] ) == 'grid' ){
  echo "This is Grid view";
}
```

This condition is not working. If I change "view" to "view_1" and "view_2" from URL then my condition is working as well.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['view_1'] ) == 'list' ){
  echo "This is List view";
 }else if( isset($_GET['view_2'] ) == 'grid' ){
  echo "This is Grid view";
 }
?>
<br>
<a href="?view_1=list">List View</a> <br>
<a href="?view_2=grid">Grid View</a>
```

But I don't want to change the "view" key. I just want to keep the same key and different value for both URL to do the conditional statement.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think not need to `isset( $_GET['view_1'] `.use just  `$_GET['view_1'] `

Comment: @HikmatSijapati - He needs `isset()` but he's using it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset()` only checks if a variable exists and isn't null and returns a boolean (true/false).

To check the value, you first need to check if it exists (isset) and then check the value, like this::

```
if (isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] == 'list') {
    // your code here.
}
```

You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

#### Alternative

If you want to make your code and conditions slightly more readable, you could to this:

```
// Get the value of $_GET['view'] once, if it exists (pre PHP 7)
$view = isset($_GET['view']) ? $_GET['view'] : null;

// PHP 7.x (new shorter syntax for the above)
$view = $_GET['view'] ?? null;


if ($view == 'list') {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @MagnusEriksson. It's worked as well.
BTW, you missed a quotation in `['view]`. I understand that :)

Comment: @MdJwelMiah - Ah, sorry about that. I'm use to IDE's that fixes that automatically. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this..

```
if(isset($_GET['view']))
{
     if($_GET['view'] == 'list')
     {
      //code here
     }
    elseif ($_GET['view'] == 'grid')
    {
    //code here
    }
}
```